# Open a lightning web component using custom button on related list

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-button, related-list

**Hi everyone I have this requirement where I have to call a lightning web component by clicking on a custom button on the related list. Little confused, can this be achieved? As seen in the below screenshot I want to launch my lightning web component after clicking on new button. Any alternatives will also work. Please suggest something! Thanks! [image]**

Comment: what have you researched or looked into? What have you tried?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I have researched through various links but did not get any proper reference to achieve this.

Comment: I'd suggest you [edit] your question to include those various links and something specific you were interested in implementing but could not achieve (and any starting components you may have written).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps

1. Wrap your lightning web component inside a URL addressable aura component
2. Create a list button with URL on the child object and put the URL of the aura component inside that with merge fields if any required.
3. Go to the parent objects page layout, click the related list and add the button on the page layout.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked for me.